# Mesos Resources Best Practices

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I was wondering if there were any best practices for restricting the amount of resources available to Mesos.  Specifically, CPU resources.  We have a busy mesos cluster running CPU intensive tasks within docker containers.  Is it a good idea to reserve one or two cores for non-mesos tasks?  Or is allowing mesos to offer all of the available CPUs on the machine just fine?

A link to some best practices regarding resources would be great as well.  The almighty Google wasn't very productive.  I'd just like some advice and hopefully evidence that this is a good idea before suggesting we move forward down this path.

Thanks!